# Pattern match for the existence of an attribute present in a case class

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

Here is an example case class:

`case class Person(  firstName: Either[Unit, String],
                     middleName: Either[Unit, Option[String],
                     lastName: Either[Unit,String])`

Any time I get an instance of this case class with a `middleName` it is invalid and I want to do something, all other cases are ok.

**EDIT**

To clarify. I need to guard against using an instance of this case class in a certain method if it was constructed with a `middleName`. So I would want to do something like this:

```
person match {
    case Person(_,m,_) => halt()
    case _ => continue()
}
```

I'm just having a hard time thinking about the types involved here.

Comment: These are some strange types. What is it that you want to match about `middleName`? When it is `Left` or `Right`, or some `Right` with a specific value (or `None`)?

Comment: Can you add the code of your pattern matching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your pattern matching does not test the actual value of `middleName`, it simply assigns it to `m`. All `Person` instances are gonna match this first case.

If you want to call `halt` if `middleName` is a `Right` for example you should write:

```
person match {
  case Person(_, Right(_), _) => halt() 
  case _ => continue()
}
```

If you want to dive into the value of `Right` to see if it's a `Some`:

```
person match {
  case Person(_, Right(Some(_)), _) => halt() 
  case _ => continue()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, still learning the ropes with pattern matching :)